# Google Analytics - Conversion tracking based on external factor

Tags: php, google-analytics

Hello fellow (stack)flowers,

I have an website where a customer can submit his or hers website URL. When the person submits his or hers website URL, this website gets queued up in a external system. The purpose of the external system is to analyze the given website. After analyzing the website, the external system sends an mail to the customer with a price.

Now the question is, how do I associate this price (fetched by the external system) and the Google Analytics entry of tracking the customer?

The requirements of getting the website queued up, is:

1. His or hers email address
2. The website URL that needs to be analyzed

If anybody could hint me in a direction, it would be very much appreciated. :)

Comment: do you need His or hers email address to  Google Analytics Console? or???

Comment: No, I don't - the email address is used for sending an email to the person explaining them the price

Comment: can add code what ever you tryed

Comment: The question is more like, how is it possible to change an entry in Google Analytics based on data from an external system - I don't really have any specific code, that will help you understand the concept of it, sorry.